Best Practices for Upgrading the Installed Packages in Salesforce Without Overloading Testing Team
We have a Salesforce environment with around 20-25 managed packages, and every other week one or the other has an upgrade available. Our testing team has limited capacity, and we don't want to overload them with testing every time an upgrade is made. At the same time, we also need to plan for testing the Salesforce seasonal release every 4 months.
Given this scenario, what are some best practices and recommendations to efficiently manage the upgrades of these installed packages while ensuring that our testing team isn't overwhelmed?
One approach I was considering is to shuffle the managed package upgrades to coincide with the Salesforce release testing (during the preview window). This way, we can test the packages during the preview window and upgrade them at least once or twice a year. Is this a good approach, or are there better strategies for handling frequent package upgrades without overloading our testing efforts?
Would appreciate any suggestions or tips on how to approach this challenge or if you share how your company is managing it.
